# Figuring out how much torque dc motor will need to run at a certain speed. (E-skateboard project)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, motors, torque

Suppose I want to purchase a DC motor online, how can i determine how much torque my motor will need to run at a certain speed? I.e. 15mph

This is for my electric skateboard project and the load on top of the board will be 140 lbs.

Really having a hard time figuring this out and was hoping someone can share their knowledge.

Comment: the first thing I'd do is investigate whats available commercially. I'm not going to do a search for you but I'd be surprised if you cant find a web forum full of electric skateboard enthusiasts telling you what motors they use.

Answer (score 1):

For any powered vehicle the maximum speed on level ground is determined by the sum of the forces resisting its movement. These forces can be roughly broken down into:

- Rolling resistance : between the wheels and the road surface
- Internal friction from bearing, transmission etc
- Air resistance

Typically the first two will be either more or less constant or proportional to speed, air resistance (drag) tends to increase with the square of speed and it is this which is generally the limiting factor on top speed.

So if you apply a constant torque to the wheels the vehicle will continue to accelerate untill the accelerating force is equal to the retarding force.

The powered wheels convert torque to force with the relationship T = Fr , where T = Torque at the wheel axle, F = Force and r = wheel radius.

[This page](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/drag-coefficient-d_627.html) details how to estimate drag forces and provides a coefficient for a standing person.

To estimate friction forces a simple method is to load up the board with the approriate weight and uses a spring balanc to determine the force required to just get it moving, this is a bit crude but should give you a ballpark estimate.

In terms of selecting a motor you will need to consult the [torque curve](http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html) for the motor which describes teh relationship between torque and RPM will also influence what overall gear ratio you need.

Of course maximum speed is no the only thing you need to consider you also need enough torque to provide adequate acceleration and hill-climbing as well as taking bulk, weight and your power supply into account.